# How to Access the Confidence on Pocket Sphinx Transcription

Tags: python, speech-recognition, pocketsphinx

I am converting audio to text using sphinx, and I can't find how to access the confidence score for each word

I am able to access the transcription output, but I can't get the estimated probabilities behind the model. This feels basic, but I can't find the proper documentation. What should I add to the below?

````
test = sr.AudioFile(audio_file)
Recon = sr.Recognizer()

with test as source:
    test_audio = Recon.record(source)
text = Recon.recognize_sphinx(test_audio,language = 'en-US')```
````

Answer (score 1):

Confidence result **is not returned** by the current version of `speech-recognition`. If you look at the [implementation](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/speech_recognition/__init__.py#L753):

```py
def recognize_sphinx(...):
   ...
   # return results
   hypothesis = decoder.hyp()
   if hypothesis is not None: return hypothesis.hypstr
   raise UnknownValueError()  # no transcriptions available
```

you will see that only the text result (`hypothesis.hypstr`) is returned, while the confidence is in `hypothesis.prob`. A quick workaround would be to copy-paste the [entire method](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/speech_recognition/__init__.py#L753) after installing pocketsphinx alone:

> pip install pocketsphinx

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what do you mean by copy-paste the entire method?

Comment: I meant to follow the link, copy the source code, and paste it into your project.

Comment: what about overloading the recognize_sphinx method in your project: you define your own flavour of the method then you do a r.recognize_sphinx = my_own_private_method()

Comment: @AlexandreMazel That might work as well.